# How do i convert WMD markdown syntax to HTML on my site?

Tags: python, html, django, markdown, wmd

Am using django and am implementing WMD on my site, am just wondering how do i convert the markdown syntax to HTML for display purposes, is there some sort of function i should call to do this conversion?

What is the best way to handle markdown ie. do i save the markdown as is to the database then parse it when displaying it or should i save the converted HTML then convert it to markup during editing?

Answer (score 6):

Check out the [markup](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.0/ref/contrib/#markup) add-on which comes with Django. That is what you are looking for.

> To activate these filters, add 'django.contrib.markup' to your INSTALLED_APPS setting. Once you’ve done that, use {% load markup %} in a template, and you’ll have access to these filters. For more documentation, read the source code in django/contrib/markup/templatetags/markup.py.

Also check out [this article](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Django) for some more details if you're still stuck.

Comment: Any nodejs version?